# How to use perMessageDeflate in a websocket server that uses along side express?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I have a websocket server and I wish to use `perMessageDeflate` along with `express` in my config.

I currently have :

```
const server = createServer({
  cert: readFileSync('/path/to/cert.pem'),
  key: readFileSync('/path/to/key.pem')
});
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ server });
```

and according to [documentation](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#new-websocketserveroptions-callback) I need to make the connection into :

```
const wss = new WebSocketServer({
  port: 8080,
  perMessageDeflate: {
    zlibDeflateOptions: {
      // See zlib defaults.
      chunkSize: 1024,
      memLevel: 7,
      level: 3
    },
```

Yet I am not sure how I can add `perMessageDeflate` object to `new WebSocketServer({ server })` as an argument.

How can I use it as an argument while having `{ server }`?

Answer (score 0):

To use the `perMessageDeflate` option with the `WebSocketServer` while having the `server` object as an argument, you can modify your code as follows:

```js
const server = createServer({
  cert: readFileSync('/path/to/cert.pem'),
  key: readFileSync('/path/to/key.pem')
});

const wss = new WebSocketServer({
  server,
  perMessageDeflate: {
    zlibDeflateOptions: {
      // See zlib defaults.
      chunkSize: 1024,
      memLevel: 7,
      level: 3
    }
  }
});
```

In the code above, you pass both the `server` object and the `perMessageDeflate` configuration as properties to the `WebSocketServer` constructor.

By providing the `server` object as an argument, you ensure that the WebSocket server is created using the existing HTTP/S server. The `perMessageDeflate` property is added as part of the configuration object passed to the `WebSocketServer` constructor.

This way, you can use the `perMessageDeflate` option while still using the `server` object in your WebSocket server setup.

Make sure to adjust the port and other configurations as needed in your actual code.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: great answer! just out of curiosity, did you get this from chatgpt?